# An attribute value from CSS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

There's a way to select a certain data in CSS like this:

```
  td[data-cell|="n"] {
       background-color: red;
       margin-top: 10px;
      ...
     }
```

Where `n` - is a beginning of `td's data-cell`  attribute.

How to use this selector's combination in Javascript? Because JS's will recognize this likely as an array and return Error.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific on how you plan to "use" this selector in JavaScript. But since you usually pass selectors as a string I don't see how the interpreter could think that it's an array.

Comment: I meant those brackets which used for an array [...]. Anyway, I need to get a beginning of a data-cell attribute. The easiest way seemed to be making like that.

Answer (score -1):

All modern browsers support [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for a single element, and [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) for an array of elements.  The parameter passed to these functions is a CSS selector.  So your selector would remain unchanged.

```
var firstTD = document.querySelector('td[data-cell|="n"]');
```

or

```
var firstTD = document.querySelectorAll('td[data-cell|="n"]')[0];
```

> querySelectorAll has nothing to do with ES6, 5, or any other ECMAScript. - dfsq

Thanks for pointing this out. I was thinking it was dependent on ES6 for some reason.  Rather it is part of Web API, which is implemented natively for modern browsers.

For backwards compatibility you can use a selector lib, such as jQuery.

```
var firstTD = $('td[data-cell|="n"]')[0]; // or .eq(0)
```

> ^ is not the same thing as |= - Juhana

I couldn't agree more.  This line threw me off...

> Where n - is a beginning of td's data-cell attribute. - Alexandr Belov

Not knowing what form the value of `data-cell` takes, I wasn't sure if he wanted an actual "starts with".  To get a true "starts with" you would want `^=`.

From [w3 css selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation):

> **[att|=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute, its value
>   either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately
>   followed by "-" (U+002D).

---

Alternatively you can access the data properties of DOM elements using the  [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

```
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(obj, idx, arr) {
    // simulate '|=' filter
    if(obj.dataset.cell &&
       (obj.dataset.cell === "n" ||
        obj.dataset.cell.startsWith("n-"))) {
         alert(obj.dataset.cell);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you make the same in JS? Without JQuery.

Comment: `^` is not the same thing as `|=`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` has nothing to do with ES6, 5, or any other ECMAScript.